# How to loop through JSON object that is array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I just need to retrieve an object by its id from this JSON object (peopleData). When I do `typeof peopleData`, it returns object. When I try to do `typeof peopleData[0]` (treating this object as an array because it has brackets as the opening and closing elements) it returns `undefined`. How do I loop through all of the objects to find the appropriate object if this JSON object is an array that returns "undefined" when I try to get a specific element of that array? I don't know how to enumerate over or de-structure this object since it is an array.

Here are the first few lines from the JSON that I was given (I changed the values but that is irrelevant. I am mainly emphasizing the bracket at the beginning). This is the raw JSON object that I copied from its raw form on GitHub:

```
[{
    "id": "237856238235",
    "ip_address": "3423423.42.42.4",
    "ssn": "123133231",
    "date_of_birth": "3123123",
    "address": {
        "home": {
            "street_number": "231231",
            "street_name": "ef2ef23",
            "street_suffix": "8i6rth2",
            "city": "wefwdfwef"
            "state": "affwefwfww",
            "zip": "wefsdfbghyj"
        },
        "work": {
            "street_number": "wefgwegwe",
            "street_name": "wefwefwf",
            "street_suffix": "wsfaf",
            "city": "aefaef",
            "state": "afaef",
            "zip": "aefaef"
        }
    }
}, {
    "id": "fwefewf",
    "ip_address": "fwefwf",
    "ssn": "wfwef",
    "date_of_birth": "wefwef",
    "address": {
        "home": {
            "street_number": "efwef",
```

I have done this before with this exact data and it worked when I just used a small function that cycles through each element of the array, but I have no idea why it is not working now.

Comment: Did you parse the JSON? ```JSON.parse(<my_json_here>)```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: What you are showing is invalid JSON, since it cuts off in the middle of a nested object. Be sure that this is what you are receiving in the browser. Just because that's what GitHub shows doesn't mean it isn't getting mangled somewhere along the way...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I said that this is just the top part. I only copied that much as an example to show in the question. I am using Axios to get the JSON file, which is hosted on github.

Comment: @S.Ramjit I have done this before without having to parse and parsing here gives me an error.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the github link you're pulling the data from? As @HereticMonkey it could be that your JSON is malformed or you're not actually getting back a JSON string but an array/object

Comment: ... And? There are many ways data can become garbled in transit. It may be stored as ASCII, transmitted as UTF-8 with a BOM, and interpreted as EBCDIC. We don't know, since all you've provided us with a sample of something from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I diagnosed my problem incorrectly. It did not have to do with the JSON data. I forgot to use `await` when getting the data with Axios. Thanks so much for any effort you put in to help me with this.

Comment: In that case, it's probably better to close the question as not reproducible

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter by the id you want.

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "237856238235",
    "ip_address": "3423423.42.42.4",
    "ssn": "123133231",
    "date_of_birth": "3123123",
    "address": {
      "home": {
        "street_number": "231231",
        "street_name": "ef2ef23",
        "street_suffix": "8i6rth2",
        "city": "wefwdfwef",
        "state": "affwefwfww",
        "zip": "wefsdfbghyj"
      },
      "work": {
        "street_number": "wefgwegwe",
        "street_name": "wefwefwf",
        "street_suffix": "wsfaf",
        "city": "aefaef",
        "state": "afaef",
        "zip": "aefaef"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "fwefewf",
    "ip_address": "fwefwf",
    "ssn": "wfwef",
    "date_of_birth": "wefwef",
    "address": {
      "home": {
        "street_number": "efwef",
        "street_name": "ef2ef23",
        "street_suffix": "8i6rth2",
        "city": "wefwdfwef",
        "state": "affwefwfww",
        "zip": "wefsdfbghyj"
      },
      "work": {
        "street_number": "wefgwegwe",
        "street_name": "wefwefwf",
        "street_suffix": "wsfaf",
        "city": "aefaef",
        "state": "afaef",
        "zip": "aefaef"
      }
    }
  }]
let result = data.filter(obj => obj.id === "237856238235")
//console.log(result)
console.log(result[0])
```

Comment: And if `data` is coming back as an object instead of an array, as the OP says?

Comment: The OP said it is an array. ..." I don't know how to enumerate over or de-structure this object since it is an array"... should mention and post in his question the exact data he gets.

Comment: "When I do `typeof peopleData`, it returns object. " Ask clarifying questions in comments on the question *before answering*.

Comment: typeof array returns object. Pls check this before commenting